# Can I build an OPML file from a list of website URLs?

Tags: rss, opml

This happens a lot so I wonder if there's a tool for working around it. Often, I find a website with a blogroll or a links page with a long list of 20 or more websites. I sure would like to keep up with those sites via the feed reader of my choice, but it sure it tedious to click on each and every link, look for an RSS link, subscribe to that, wash, rinse, repeat.

My favorite feed reader will accept an OPML to batch import a list of feeds, so that's a start, but here's my question:

If all I have is a list of the website URLs, is there a way to generate an OPML of the RSS feeds?

Comment: I wish such a service existed! Also, if someone is willing to build that, I want a service that given my twitter handle will export an OPML list of all the sites of the people i follow... That'd be so convenient!

Comment: I did find a PHP script that looks like a promising opportunity, assuming you've got the chops and the setup to run a PHP scrips, which I do, so I'll try it. 

http://skinofstars.com/2010/03/php-script-rss-auto-discovery-opml-file/

Comment: I found this method as well, but I'm afraid I don't understand it
http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/10/23/feed-detection-from-blog-url-lists-with-opml-output/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create an OPML file. All I had to do was create a text file, with a URL on each line. Then, [I was able to use a PHP script](http://skinofstars.com/2010/03/php-script-rss-auto-discovery-opml-file/) to look at each URL, hunt each for the RSS feed's address and add each RSS feed address to the OPML file.

Incidentally, I've shared the project that this is part of on Github. I wanted to be able to [subscribe to lots of litblogs at once](https://github.com/dylan-k/litkit).